# C++ Vectors: Error in calling push_back

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am executing the following code, but I am getting the following error messages:

error: request for member 'push_back' in 'vec1', which is of non-class type 'std::vector [5]'

error: request for member 'push_back' in 'vec2', which is of non-class type 'std::vector [5]'

error: no match for 'operator*' in 'vec1[i] * vec2[i]'

I am trying to multiply two vectors(by dynamically taking input) and storing the result in an array using pointer notation. Please help me out? Thank you!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value1, value2;

    int length;

    cout << "Please enter the size of the vectors" << endl;
    cin >> length;

    vector<int> vec1[5];
    vector<int> vec2[5];

    cout << "Please enter the values for vector 1" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cin >> value1;
        vec1.push_back(value1);
    }

    cout << "Please enter the values for vector 2" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cin >> value2;
        vec2.push_back(value2);
    }

    int *ptr = new int[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        ptr[i] = vec1[i] * vec2[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout << *(ptr + i) << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `vector<int> vec1[5];` Do you really want an array of vectors?

Comment: `storing the result in an array using pointer notation.`  You can still use a vector and use `pointer notation` without using new[]: `std::vector<int> vec3(length); int *ptr = &vec3[0]` Otherwise your code has a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose you should use:-

```
vector<int> vec1; 
vector<int> vec2;
```

then reserve whatever amount you want

```
vec1.reserve(5);
vec2.reserve(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The vectors have to be defined like

```
vector<int> vec1;
vector<int> vec2;
```

instead of

```
vector<int> vec1[5];
vector<int> vec2[5];
```

Also after the definitions of the vectors you could reserve memory for their potential elements:

```
vec1.reserve( length );
vec2.reserve( length );
```

And do not forget to delete the allocated dynamically array

```
delete [] ptr;
```

Also it would be better if length would be declared as having type `size_t` instead of `int`. In this case you need not to check whether it has a negative value.